# In Visual studio code , python debugging extension keep install for so long

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation

I am new to vs code. I tried to download python debug extension but it keeps downloading for 3-4 hour. I am very worried about it.

[image: here is a picture]

I have Window 8.
I have python3.7 downloaded on my system.
Also edited link the system variable.

Comment: Hi Aamir, are you behind a proxy? If not, could you please check the installation log file to locate the detail error/warning message during the installation. If you try to install other extension, does this issue persists or not?